Next.js 14.2.4 generateStaticParams throw error
Project structure
├── app/
│   ├── [work]/
│   │   └── page.js
│   ├── works/
│   │   ├── work1.js
│   │   ├── work2.js
│   │   └── work3.js
├── next.config.mjs

Here is the /[work]/page.js
import Work1 from "../works/Work1";
import Work2 from "../works/Work2";
import Work3 from "../works/Work3";

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [
    { id: "work-1" }
    { id: "work-2" }
    { id: "work-3" }
  ]:
}

export default function WorkPage({ params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  // const work = params.work; <- If I use "work" below it works fine

  const project = (id) => {
    switch (id) {
      case "work-1":
        return <Work1 />;
      case "work-2":
        return <Work2 />;
      case "work-3":
        return <Work3 />;
      default:
        return <h1>Something went wrog.</h1>;
    }
  };

  return <div>{project(id)}</div>;
}

and here is my nexjs.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: { unoptimized: true },
};

export default nextConfig;


When I run npm run dev I get this error message:

Error: Page "/[work]/page" is missing param "/work-1"  in "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output: export" config.


So apparently the issue was because the folder is named [work] and in the generateStaticParams function I was using "id" - that property must be the same as the value you use in the folder, so in this case
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [
    { work: "work-1" },
    { work: "work-2" },
    { work: "work-3" },
  ];
}

and then, use it like so
export default function WorkPage({ params }) {
  const { work } = params;

  let WorkComponent;
  if (work === "work-1") {
    WorkComponent = Work1;
  } else if (work === "work-2") {
    WorkComponent = Work2;
  } else if (work === "work-3") {
    WorkComponent = Work3;
  } else {
    WorkComponent = () => <div>Work not found</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Work Page for {work}</h1>
      <WorkComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

